# What does IRS TREAS 310 TAX REF 0918 mean?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I filed my 2019 tax return. In a checking account I haven't used in years on my returns I received a deposit that says IRS TREAS 310 TAX REF 0918. In the checking account I used for my 2019 return I received a memo from the bank that the stimulus check would be deposited by 4/15. That deposit says IRS TREAS 310 TAX REF. When I go in the IRS website to search for my refund, it shows the amount of the stimulus deposit on the 4/15 but not my refund expected from my return.

Comment: when did you submit your return? when was the last time you used that checking account with the IRS? how much was the IRS TREAS 310 TAX REF 0918 transaction?

Comment: I efiled my tax return the first week in April. The IRS TREAS 310 TAX REF 0918 was $657.25 and deposited to a checking account I haven't used for my tax returns in over 5 yrs.